# Android Studio: Write(FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm struggling with this write file that I will use to save double numbers (number + "\n"   I want to have a number for line). I have a similar code that works with OutputStream instead of FileWriter but the OutputStream override the last number.

With the FileWritter I don't create the file, look the logcat:

```
07-08 08:44:08.316    3076-3076/com.example.emilio.notification W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: test3.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

This is the writecode:

```
    private void writeMyArray(double rate) {

    try{
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter("test3.txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(Double.toString(rate)+"\n");
        Log.i("MyActivity", "a rate é:" + rate);
        bufferWritter.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I create the file, since it will be located inside the internal storage of the device.

I've done a research and I found a question that is the same as mine but don't have a correct answer. I tried this:

```
PrintWriter fileWritter = new PrintWriter(new File(this.getFilesDir(), "testfile.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

and in log cat I have this error:

```
     07-08 09:17:04.005  16463-16463/com.example.emilio.notification      W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

can someone help? Sorry for my bad english

PS: I didn't saw nothing in this documentation that should fit in my code: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Did you add the permission in your manifest ?

Comment: @PrerakSola this code:   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/> ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but you can try it:

```
private void writeMyArray(double rate) {

    try{
        String filename = "test3.txt";
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(Double.toString(rate)+"\n");
        Log.i("MyActivity", "a rate é:" + rate);
        bufferWritter.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I write instead of context?

Comment: You need to get the application context. Your `writeMyArray()` is in which class? Does that class extend `Activity` ?

Comment: It's in MainActivity and extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: Replace `context` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: It returns the second logcat "code" that I wrote in the question.